# Adding an Object with multiple Key Value pairs to array in PHP

Tags: php

Its something which did sound trivial to me, but when started doing it is throwing its own challenges.

I will explain the structure I am trying to create:

```
[
 parent_key1 = [
                 [
                  child_key1 => 10,
                  child_key2 => 20
                 ],
                 [
                  child_key1 => 50,
                  child_key2 => 40
                 ]
               ],

 parent_key2 = [
                 [
                  child_key1 => 40,
                  child_key2 => 80
                 ],
                 [
                  child_key1 => 70,
                  child_key2 => 60
                 ]
               ],
 parent_key3 = [
                 [
                  child_key1 => 40,
                  child_key2 => 60
                 ],
                 [
                  child_key1 => 90,
                  child_key2 => 30
                 ]
               ]
]
```

So, to explain, I have the `Parent Array` which has `parent_key1`,`parent_key2` etc stored in it.

The `parent_key1` itself contains an array which has multiple arrays of `key,value` pairs stored in it.

So, coming to my problem :

1. Given I added one array object of child key value pairs to parent key. When I need to insert another array object to same parent_key of main array, then how can I do that.

Comment: Please share your request array that set above pattern

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar The example above is the array I want to create.

Comment: Will it have child till 2 ?

Comment: @AbhiBurk I gave an example, it can have n child_keys

Comment: Something like `$array['parent_key1'][] = $child_array;` (where `$child_array = ['child_key1' => x, 'chlld_key2' => y]`